# Why this method gives me an error?

Tags: hibernate

The method:

```
public Mainsubjects getChosenMain(String loc, int id) {
  List  list = hibernateTemplate.find("from Mainsubjects where locale = ? and id = ?", loc, id);
  Mainsubjects main = (Mainsubjects) list.get(0);
  return main;
}
```

gives me:

```
getChosenMain(java.lang.String,int) in fi.utu.tuha.db.DatabaseOperations cannot implement getChosenMain(java.lang.String,int) in fi.utu.tuha.db.DatabaseManager
return type fi.utu.tuha.domain.Mainsubjects is not compatible with java.util.List<fi.utu.tuha.domain.Mainsubjects>
```

I wonder why. I'm casting the object to return it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `DatabaseOperations` implements the interface, or extends the class `DatabaseManager`. This interface or base class has the method:

```
public List<Mainsubjects> getChosenMain(String,int)
```

You have overriden the method with:

```
public Mainsubjects getChosenMain(String loc, int id)
```

The cause of the error is that the return types do not match.

Comment: Right. How blind I was once again!